# Refinement of an open cover for a simply connected compact subset

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology

Let $U$ denote a simply connected, open subset of the plane, and let $K$ be a simply connected, compact subset of $U$. Can we always find a finite or countable sequence of open disks $(D_n)$ such that:

- $K \subseteq \bigcup_n D_n$.
- $D_n \subseteq U$ for every $n$.
- $D_n \cap \bigcup_{k<n} D_k$ is non-empty and connected for every $n$.

The case when $U$ is the whole plane is trivial. Otherwise, $\bar U$ is closed and non-empty, so the distance of $K$ to $\bar U$ exists and is positive, call it $\epsilon$. We can then cover $K$ by all the disks centered at its points with radius $\epsilon$ and, by compactness, extract a finite sequence of disks with radius $\epsilon$ that covers $K$.

My intuition (which might be wrong!) is that if we proceed iteratively from any such disk and, at any point in the process, we cannot find a disk satisfying the second condition, then $K$ must have a hole—but I haven’t found a way to formalize it.

Is there an obvious counterexample I am missing? If not, is this a known result and could I please have a proof, or a reference to a proof?

Comment: A possible attempt: what if $K$ is a continuum which is simply connected but not tree like and $U$ is small enough so that every disk in $U$ has diameter less than $\varepsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is such that there is no $\epsilon$-map from $K$ to a tree?

Comment: Is the collection of disks $(D_n)_n$ supposed to be a cover $K$? (The question does not give any relation between $K$ and $(D_n)_n$)

Comment: Elaborating on my previous comment, how do you cover the warsaw circle when $U$ is small enough to not contain the whole central "hole"?

Comment: Indeed, the Warsaw circle should work as a counterexample if $U$ misses some point of the hole. Because then $\bigcup_nD_n$ has to contain a non contractible loop, and then letting $D_k$ be the first disk such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^kD_i$ is not simply connected we can obtain a contradiction by Seifert-van Kampen

Comment: Yes, apologies, the original formulation failed to mention that 1. the disks need to cover $K$ and 2. the open set must be simply connected (otherwise even the circle is a counter example).